# Gravar em arquivo csv

Tags: python, csv

Tenho uma função que retorna uma linha e essa deve ser inserida em um arquivo CSV.  A linha possui a seguinte estrutura quando retornada pela função: `['x' - 'y', 'z', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]`.

Quando tento a inserção, usando o método `csv.writerow`, todos os caracteres são entendidos como um campo. E não é esse o comportamento que preciso.

A linha acima para o propósito da aplicação deveria ser inserida da seguinte forma: `x - y`, o primeiro campo; `z`, o segundo; e `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`, o terceiro e último.

Algum companheiro passou por situação parecida que poderia me ajudar?

O que tentei fazer:

Código para inserção:

```
with open(arquivoSaida, 'at') as resultado:
    arqGravar = csv.writer(resultado)
    arqGravar.writerow(comparaNumeros(linhaAnterior, linhaPosterior))
```

Função que gera a saída a ser inserida:

```
def comparaNumeros(linha, proxima):
    numerosRep = []
    totalRep = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= 15:
        j = 1
        while j <= 15:
            if linha[i] == proxima[j]:
                totalRep += 1
                numerosRep.append(linha[i])
                break
            else:
                j += 1
        i += 1
    csvLinha = linha[0] + " - " + proxima[0] + "," + str(totalRep) + "," + str(numerosRep)
    #print(csvLinha)
    return csvLinha
```

Comment: Que linguagem? Poderia colocar o seu código na pergunta?

Comment: A linguagem é python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na pergunta, você cita que a função te retorna:

```
['x' - 'y', 'z', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Mas na função você retornou:

```
csvLinha = linha[0] + " - " + proxima[0] + "," + str(totalRep) + "," + str(numerosRep)
```

São coisas bem distintas. O primeiro é uma lista, enquanto o segundo é uma *string*. Talvez o que você queria fazer é:

```
csvLinha = [linha[0] + '-' + proxima[0], totalRep, numerosRep]
```

Desta forma, sim, o que será retornado segue conforme o esperado.

Se estiver utilizando Python 3.6 ou superior, o primeiro valor pode ser gerado a partir de uma *f-string*:

```
csvLinha = [f'{linha[0]} - {proxima[0]}', totalRep, numerosRep]
```

Comment: Vou corrigir e retorno o resultado.

Comment: Caro Anderson, corrigiu sim. Com um pequeno ajuste no primeiro campo. Sua resposta fez linha[0] - proxima[0]; a alteração foi linha[0] + "-" + proxima[0]. Sou novato em python, por isso peco em detalhes intrísecos à linguagem. Mas aprenderei. Muito obrigado pela pronta resposta. Agora vou corrigir o código de gravação.